# How to resolve the error when installing scikit-learn in Linux

Tags: python

I get an error when I try to install sckit-learn on Linux Jetson using the command:

```
pip3 install scikit-learn
```

The error message shows:

```
"/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;file='/tmp/pip-build-_6p4l1qb/numpy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ttk4rc2k-record/install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-_6p4l1qb/numpy/
```

Does anyone know why I get this error and how to fix it?

Comment: This may be because you are trying to do a system wide installation without sudo. Try `pip3 install --user scikit-learn`.

Comment: thanks for replying, but it doesn't it, unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [*scikit-learn* software](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/) is [packaged in APT](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python3-sklearn), so you can install it with

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-sklearn
```

and then proceed with [Getting Started](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/getting_started.html).

Comment: thank you kind ser, your solution worked splendidly, but not i'm encounter another problem. I'm trying to upgrade my numpy version but the command with pip3 won't worked (it show the same error as above) . Can you please help me one more time?

Comment: wait, i figure it out. I manage to update it, but it said that 1.13.3 is already the newest version? but my code said that it needed version 1.14.5 or above? I'm confused

Comment: The answer depends on Ubuntu version. For example 20.04 LTS [has 1.17](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python3-numpy). What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: it's 18.04 LTS, So i need to upgrade to ubuntu 20.04 in order for it to work?

Comment: Upgrade to 20.04 LTS sounds reasonable in case of broken pip3.

Comment: Unfortunately , my machine(nano jetson) is now not supporting ubuntu 20.04. Do we have any other way?

Comment: You can try reinstallation of 18.04 LTS and then try to install python packages using `pip3`.

Comment: appreciated, thanks for your time man